# Collection View iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

When i put my app in iOS 7, the top cell gets cover by my navigation bar.
I tried using edgesForExtendedLayout but it just gives my an iOS 6 look of the app. 
I'm trying to take advantage of the translucent bar in iOS 7 but edgesForExtendedLayout doesn't help.

Is there a way to make this cell appear below de the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options. `UICollectionView` is a subview of `UIScrollView`.

The most simple method is to turn your view controller into a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`, which takes care of these issues automatically. More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html).

If you cannot, either set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `YES` in your view controller, or manually set the contentInsets of your collection view manually in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` like so:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews]

    [_collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0)];
    [_collectionView setScrollIndicatorInsets: _collectionView.contentInset];
}
```

Additional benefit of using `UICollectionViewController` is the support of `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions`, which can create cool transitions between collection view layouts (like, for example, Apple's mobile calendar app).

Comment: it worked thanks, but it didnt work with self.topLayoutGuide.length i just put the coordinates my self.

Comment: For webView: `webview.scrollView setContentInset:...`